# Text editor to help summarizing textbooks

Tags: linux, text-editor, knowledge-organization

I read a lot of textbooks, and I have always wanted to summarize the things I read and organize them but working with normal text editors like Microsoft Word(or LibreOffice) is really hard and dissuades you from ever making a summary.

I need a software that is:

- Simple
- Helps me summarize and organize the things I have read
- Allows importing of all kinds like pictures, animated GIFs, etc.
- Runs on Linux

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) suite of products.

- Browser Plug-ins
- Desktop Client for Windows/OS-X *not Linux yet* ***but***:
- Online editor - *see screenshot below* and some possible Linux Evernote interfaces [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-interesting-third-party-evernote-clients-linux-mac/).
- Editor can attach links, code fragments, images, files, etc.
- Android & iOS applications
- Clip sections of text within the browser, *or bookmarks, images, etc.*, using the plug in.
- Clip sections within pdf documents.
- Notes are stored online and automatically synced between devices, you can make a quick note on your phone and then expand it from your PC & vice-versa.

[image]
[image: Clipper]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Onenote will do this, will run under Wine. Basket Note Pads is a KDE application: http://basket.kde.org.
Also see this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4jvns2/anything_similar_to_ms_onenote_for_linux/

Answer (score 0):

Tree-structured hierarchical online note-taker. 
Fast, lightweight web app for mobile devices, tablets and PCs.

https://webnote.in/